# Is it necessary to call WSACleanup before program exit

Tags: windows, winsock2, wsastartup, wsacleanup

I have a Windows socket program (XP and above) that calls `WSAStartup`. Is it necessary to call `WSACleanup` before the program exits? If I don't, will there be any negative consequences? In particular is:

```
WSACleanup();
exit(0);
```

different from merely `exit(0)`. I realise that on Win16 omitting the `WSACleanup` would leak system resources, is that still the case.

Comment: It is not necessary.  You do blow the opportunity of ever using any leak diagnostic tool again, best to code carefully in the future :)

Comment: @HansPassant, my goal is improving a binding in a garbage collected language, so losing leak diagnostics is not a problem, and calling WSACleanup is added complexity. Any reference to say it is not necessary? It seems "obvious" to me as a general rule of OS design, but I can't find it actually stated.